# In Which Location Are Mysql Compiled Procedures Stored?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can I get compiled Mysql stored procedures from their physical location?

Comment: I have  reinstalled the OS before that i have copied all thing that is located under Mysql/Data folder.Now i can able to restore all values except store procedures.is there any way to get that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the database `mysql` there's a table `proc` which seems to hold all the data for a stored procedure.
So the physical files should be <datadir>/mysql/proc.MYI and <datadir>/mysql/proc.MYD.

edit: But maybe you're simply looking for [SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-procedure.html)?

Comment: I did the above thing but same result :(.is there Any other possible Way?

Comment: No. I have reinstalled the OS before that i have copied all thing that is located under Mysql/Data folder.Now i can able to restore all values except store procedures.is there any way to get that?

Comment: hm, if you place those two files into another directory in your data dir, e.g. datadir/proctest/proc.MYI and datadir/proctest/proc.MYD and then restart the mysql server, can you access the table like e.g. `SELECT body FROM proctest.proc` ?

Comment: In order to transfer a mysql database server to a new host, you need to copy EVERYTHING under the data dir. Really everything. You can't just pick-and-choose. If you failed to copy the system "mysql" database, then the procedures are lost. Likewise, if you failed to copy the innodb tablespace, your innodb tables are lost.

Comment: Hm yes it is everything but what my fault was that I just pasted these two files into Mysql default schema.It seems Every schema has separate  files(proc.MYI and proc.MYD) but In My old mysql Database Only the default(mysql) has this.Which one is the real concept?

Comment: This information is obsolete in MySQL **8.0**. The `mysql.proc` table [is documented for MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-routines-table.html), but [is missing from the MySQL 8.0 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-routines-table.html), and indeed a query on a MySQL 8.0 database will confirm that the `mysql.proc` table _no longer exists_.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL major versions up to 5.7, the persistent source-of-truth for stored routines is [in the `mysql.proc` table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-stored-procs.html#faq-mysql-where-procedures-stored), as noted in [the accepted answer from 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1946290).

However, in MySQL major versions starting with 8.0 (released in 2018), the `mysql.proc` table no longer exists, having been [replaced by `information_schema.routines`](https://ocelot.ca/blog/blog/2017/08/22/no-more-mysql-proc-in-mysql-8-0) as the persistent source-of-truth for stored routines’ definitions.*

As to the question of *where the contents of `information_schema.routines` actually get stored on-disk*, that's somewhat tricky.

If you query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` on MySQL 8.0.x, it describes `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` as a "system view":

```sql
mysql> select * from information_schema.tables where lower(table_schema)='information_schema' and lower(table_name)='routines';
+---------------+--------------------+------------+-------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------------+
| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA       | TABLE_NAME | TABLE_TYPE  | ENGINE | VERSION | ROW_FORMAT | TABLE_ROWS | AVG_ROW_LENGTH | DATA_LENGTH | MAX_DATA_LENGTH | INDEX_LENGTH | DATA_FREE | AUTO_INCREMENT | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME | CHECK_TIME | TABLE_COLLATION | CHECKSUM | CREATE_OPTIONS | TABLE_COMMENT |
+---------------+--------------------+------------+-------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------------+
| def           | information_schema | ROUTINES   | SYSTEM VIEW | NULL   |      10 | NULL       |          0 |              0 |           0 |               0 |            0 |         0 |           NULL | 2024-02-12 22:20:48 | NULL        | NULL       | NULL            |     NULL |                |               |
+---------------+--------------------+------------+-------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, if you create a stored routine (e.g. `CREATE PROCEDURE` or `CREATE FUNCTION`) and ensure it's flushed to disk (e.g. by shutting down the MySQL server), then `grep` for a snippet of the stored routine’s SQL source code, you'll find that it *matches* for the `mysql.ibd` file in which `mysql.*` InnoDB tables are stored in MySQL 8.0.

So it appears that the source code and metadata for stored routines are in fact stored alongside `mysql.*` tables, although I cannot find any “official” documentation of this fact.

---

* The format of the `information_schema.routines` table/view is somewhat standardized, in that other relational databases [such as PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-routines.html) and [such as Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/routines-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) also support it.